# About the lower bound of complexity of sorting algorithms

Tags: sorting, mergesort, lower-bound

I am reading "Algorithms 4th edition" written by R. Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne:

> This result serves as a guide for us to know, when designing a sorting algorithm, how well we can expect to do. For example, without such a result, one might set out to try to design a compare-based sorting algorithm that uses half as many compares as does mergesort, in the worst case. The lower bound in Proposition I says that such an effort is futile - no such algorithm exists.

Is it really true that there is no compare-based sorting algorithms that uses half as many compares as does mergesort, in the worst case?

Comment: It explicitly says "compare-based".

Comment: Yes it's true. Why do you sound surprised ?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly true that you cannot do general<sup>1</sup> compare-based<sup>2</sup> sorting in better than `O(nlogn)`.  There is a mathematical proof here:

- http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/lowerbounden.htm

> Is it really true that there is no algorithms that uses half as many compares as does mergesort, in the worst case?

That is a different question entirely.  The theoretical lower bound is lg(n!) on the number of comparisons.

There may be an algorithm that uses fewer comparisons than merge sort but still fits inside the theoretical bound.  It depends on the precise implementation of merge-sort and the number of comparisons that it needs to do in the worst-case.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Analysis):

> In the worst case, the number of comparisons merge sort makes is equal to or slightly smaller than (n ⌈lg n⌉ - 2⌈lg n⌉ + 1), which is between (n lg n - n + 1) and (n lg n + n + O(lg n))

Note that these are not precise measures!

But the question of whether a "better than merge sort" algorithm exists boils down to how close "slightly smaller than (n lg n - n + 1)" is to lg (n!).

---

The other things to consider when predicting actual performance (as distinct from complexity) are:

- Other overheads in the algorithms that are hidden if you just count comparisons.
- How the algorithms perform in *common* use-cases; e.g. when the input is nearly ordered to start with.

---

<sup>1 - For example, without making assumptions about the initial order of the input list.</sup>

<sup>2 - A counting sort is `O(n)` but it doesn't rely on comparisons.</sup>

Comment: Sedgewick says "one might set out to try to design a compare-based sorting algorithm that uses half as many compares as does mergesort, in the worst case. The lower bound in Proposition I says that such an effort is futile - no such algorithm exists."

Comment: And what precisely is Proposition I?

Comment: Proposition I. No compare-based sorting algorithm can guarantee to sort N items with fewer than lg(N !) compares.

Comment: Maybe some algorithm like Heapsort needs only half comparions than mergesort.

Comment: Sedgewick proves Proposition I in the book.

Comment: What do they claim as the number of comparisons used by merge-sort?

Comment: (Yes, and the link I posted also proves it!  Assuming that "lg" means "log base 2".)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I was confused. Thank you very much Mr. Stephen C.

Comment: Well spotted.  A counting sort is O(N).  Fixed